# Debugging a dotnet.exe process crash using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asp.net-core-2.1

For some reason dotnet.exe crashes inside a .NET Core framework library async call `httpClient.SendAsync(...)` after upgrading .NET Core from 2.0 to 2.1.

Because dotnet.exe crashes that prevents Visual Studio from showing any error stack trace.

I am getting following error in Output -> Debug window, but it is not sufficient to fix the issue:

> The program '[12372] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073741819
>   (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

What other ways could I use to debug this problem, since error stack trace is not available?

Comment: run it from commandline... i typically get better errors from there instead of visual studio.... `dotnet run`

Comment: Start the application, then start a new instance of visual studio and hook it's debugger to the instance of dotnet.exe, create the error.

Comment: Make sure that you turn on "break on exceptions " when thrown not just when unhandled in the debugger.  This should show you where the exception is bein thrown from before the process crashes.